# Ajax busy indicator

Tags: ajax

How can I add a busy indicator before the Ajax popup appears on screen? I have been trying to follow several examples, but they are overly complex and very confusing for what seems should be an easy fix. Can anyone please help? Very new to Ajax. Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            var ajaxurl = 'auto.php',
            data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Start" value="Start" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the busy indicator in which element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the indicator when starting the ajax call and remove it when the call returns.

But you should fix your html (input element is only valid inside a form tag) and then you have to prevent the form submission. If you follow this rules your code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(evt){
       // preventing the form submission
        evt.preventDefault();
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'auto.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        // add indicator here (before the ajax request starts)
        var $indicator = $('<div>Ajax in progress...</div>').appendTo('body');
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // removing the indicator inside the success handler of the ajax call.
            $indicator.remove();
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to display a loading gif. Do I just add the img code in that div?

Comment: yes. or use the image instead of the div. Like you wish.

Comment: Hmm doesnt seem to do anything. I corrected the form issue, added your code, and replaced the div with an image tag pointing to a loading gif. I then created a test function that sleeps for 15 secs to test the loading image. Nothing appears on screen. After 15 secs, the normal popup window appears indicating the request is complete.

Comment: can you share your code and markup with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Never used it before, but here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fEsHVkJVkh

Comment: Hmm ok maybe this is working and something is wrong with my website hiding the image...

Comment: Found it! Yup it was an issue with my css. Pushing down to the bottom corner of the page. Thanks!!!